# C# Boolean Value Comparison Wrong?

Tags: c#, struct, equality

How is this possible? Both values are in memory and execution is suspended at a breakpoint after both values have been set. I was purplexed to find an if statement that checks if the two bools are different to be executed when the values were in fact the same. So I delved deeper using the Immediate Window at the same break point.

[image]

Curious, I stopped the program and (right at the original debug point where I noticed this inconsistency) I inserted a couple lines of code:

```
var one = true;
var two = true;
```

[image]

Did I break C# or something? How is it that of two pairs of booleans in the same method call scope (I double checked their .GetType() returns Boolean) are inconsistent using the equality operator?

Though it shouldn't matter, the first pair (where the double equals method is returning the wrong result) was gleaned from using PropertyInfo.GetValue(object target) before and after a method call that may or may not change the value of the property on the target. I'm using GetValue twice to ensure that the value of a property changed before "doing something."

I get this same result with many executions of the program, so I don't think it's a fluke with the execution environment.

Comment: "Did I break C# or something?" - Nope. Also, SELECT is not broken.

Comment: It will be easier to help if we see the actual code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't provide any code, but you mention that you're using Reflection, so maybe you declared `currentValue` and `newValue` as `object` variables. If that's the case, then you should use the [`Object.Equals`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4hkze5k.aspx) method to compare the variables for value equality:

```
if (object.Equals(currentValue, newValue))
{
    ...
}
```

[Boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) the same Boolean value twice will create two distinct objects, so the `==` operator, which checks for *reference* equality when used with two `object` variables, will return false:

```
object currentValue = true;
object newValue = true;
Console.WriteLine(currentValue == newValue); // False
Console.WriteLine(object.Equals(currentValue, newValue)); // True
```

Comment: +1 This does sound like a reference vs. value comparison problem. Hard to tell without code.

Comment: Why would bools have anything to do with references? They're value types.

Comment: @ashes999: References come into play once you box a value type.